# Kubernetes support for Internal Load Balancers in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes

I have a Kubernetes cluster that is connected over VPN to an on-premise datacentre. This cluster needs to "expose" Services to other programs running in the datacenter, but not to the Internet.

Currently I've been creating Services with type "NodePort" and then manually creating an Internal (Private) Load balancer to map an endpoint to the Cluster Node/Port combination.

However, this approach has some drawbacks:

- Having to manually add/remove Nodes from the load balancer (or have some sort of process which "scans" the list of all nodes and makes sure they're attached to the ELB)
- Having to make sure to delete the ELB when deleting a Service (the "orphan ELB" problem)

Does anyone know of any way to configure Kubernetes to bring up "Internal" load balancers in AWS instead of Externally facing ones and manage them in the same way that it does the External ones?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Per [this thread](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/17620#issuecomment-212508777), apply annotation `service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-internal` to the service definition.

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: someService
  annotations:
    - name: service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-internal
      value: 0.0.0.0/0
```

Comment: Per the linked thread, the `services` should be `service`. Additional source:https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/75dfb21018a7c36ceecf78a453683aa575b185fb/pkg/cloudprovider/providers/aws/aws.go#L77

Comment: may i know what this does exactly? it balances load within the k8s cluster, i.e. it routes requests to a replica Pod with lesser load?

Answer (score 11):

latest format is

```
annotations:
      service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-internal: true
```

Comment: Its missing the comma on "true". According to https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/load-balancing.html

Comment: for yaml config, no-quote is fine.

Answer (score 10):

The above answer's syntax is invalid in Kubernetes v1.5.2. The correct syntax is:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: someService
  annotations:
    "service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-internal": "0.0.0.0/0"
```

Answer (score 3):

As for 2021-11-01. The annotations have been marked deprecated and I have to use:

```yaml
annotations:
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-scheme: "internal"
```

You should follow this link to get up-to-date.

[Annotations - AWS Load Balancer Controller](https://kubernetes-sigs.github.io/aws-load-balancer-controller/v2.3/guide/service/annotations/#annotations)

Comment: That's for the "Ingress Controller". For the Service annotation it is still `service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-internal: "true"` (currently). See [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#internal-load-balancer)

Comment: Understand, I'm using the v2.3. It does have the note 
https://kubernetes-sigs.github.io/aws-load-balancer-controller/v2.3/guide/service/annotations/#lb-scheme